# LINQ SingleOrDefault, Brush, what I am doing wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, list, brush

I get some data over USB communication into my program -> 3 byte for RGB.

I put this bytes into "new SolidColorBrush" and I get "Brush" out.

```
Brush ColorActiveDark = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(USBred, USBGreen, USBBlue));
```

Later I search this Brush in "MyList" but alwasy take default value. Why it does not find identical value in my List?

```
_illumination.SelectedColorAN = _illumination.ColorList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Color == ColorActiveDark) ?? _illumination.ColorList[0];
```

MyList is defined so:

```
public class ColorItem
    {
        public string ColorName { get; set; }
        public Brush Color { get; set; }
    }
```

And later ColorList

```
public IList<ColorItem> ColorList { get; set; }

ColorList = new List<ColorItem>()
        {
            new ColorItem() { ColorName = "AppleGreen", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(76, 196, 23)) }, // 
            new ColorItem() { ColorName = "Mustard", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 219, 88)) }, // 
            new ColorItem() { ColorName = "Red", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0)) }, // 
            new ColorItem() { ColorName = "Device1", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 31, 0)) }, // 
            new ColorItem() { ColorName = "Device2", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0)) }, // 
            new ColorItem() { ColorName = "Device3", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(31, 0, 0)) }, // 
        };
```

Where is my error? If any question please ask. I hope that I write as simple as possible and understanding. Thanks!

Comment: have you added `ColorActiveDark ` to your list?

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that I Comparing the same instances :) Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're comparing two different *instances* of the object, which do not match.

Instead, you could search for the `ColorName` and return that:

```
_illumination.SelectedColorAN = _illumination.ColorList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ColorName == "AppleGreen") ?? _illumination.ColorList[0];
```

Or, have the RGB values stored in the `ColorItem` object to match that.

```
public class ColorItem
{
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
    public int Red { get; set; }
    public int Green { get; set; }
    public int Blue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Or even better by comparing RGB values

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the condition `x.Color == ColorActiveDark` will allways fail as you´re comparing different instances of your class. Thus `==` will check if the references are equal (which obviously they are not). What you want instead is check if some properties of your class are equal by implementing `object.Equals`:

```
class Brush {
    override bool Equals(object other) {
        Brush b = other as Brush;
        if (b == null) return false;

        return b.ColorName == this.ColorName;
    }
}
```

Or even better compare by compare the `ColorItem`-property where you also have to implement `Equals` for `ColorItem` as well:

```
public class ColorItem
{
    override bool Equals(object other) {
        ColorItem c = other as ColorItem;

        return c.Red == this.Red && c.Blue = this.Blue && c.Green == this.Green;
    }
}
```

EDIT: You shopuld also add an operator-implementation for `==`as follows for both classes:

```
public static bool operator == (Brush a, Brush b) {return a.Equals(b); }
```

And `ColorItem` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you always have value from `_illumination.ColorList[0]`. If so, thats because `SingleOrDefault` method cannot find **the only one element in your collection matched your condition** and it returns `null` (in case of using `Single` method it throws error if it cannot find single element). So you received `null` and in the end you'll get `_illumination.ColorList[0]` value.

Next is why you have `null`. You are trying to compare to objects by their references' equality, not their fields' values. If you need to compare these objects sometimes maybe it's better to overload `==` operator for this. Another possible case is to compare two objects by one (or some) valuable fields (properties). One more case is to create your specific `Expression` which you can use as a search condition